# Remove punctuation from string then put it back after replacement

Tags: c, replace, linked-list, strcmp, punctuation

My assignment was to read int input from two files. One contained a poem with misspelled words and the other contained a key with the misspelled word and the correct replacement right after.

I'm supposed to populate two linked lists with the information from each file and create a function that decodes the first file. I'm required to use pointers instead of char arrays in the linked list and at the end the program needs to print the first file with all corrections made.

I'm all good up until the decoder function needs to compare words with punctuation in them. How would i ignore punctuation without losing it in the final format.

Here's my decoder function:

```
LINK *decoder(TRANS *codet, LINK *head)
{
    LINK *currentt;
    currentt = head;
    TRANS *current;
    current = codet;
    printf("Decoding...\n");

    while (currentt != NULL)
    {
        current = codet;
        while (1)
        {
            if ()
            printf("Comparing %s with %s: \n", currentt->words, current->word1);
            if (!strcmp(currentt->words, current->word1))
            {
                printf("Replacing...\n");
                currentt->words = (char*)calloc(strlen(current->word2), sizeof(char));
                strcpy(currentt->words, current->word2);
                break;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
        currentt = currentt->next;  
    }

    return head;
}
```

Here's the rest of my code:

```
//Tristan Shepherd

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct node
{
    char *words;
    struct node *next;
};

struct codex
{
    char *word1;
    char *word2;
    struct codex *next;
};

typedef struct node LINK;
typedef struct codex TRANS;

void printInsert(LINK *head) 
{
    printf("\n\nPrinting list: \n\n");
    LINK *current;
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s ", current->words);
        current = current->next;
    } 
}

void printCodex(TRANS *codet) 
{
    printf("\n\nPrinting code: \n\n");
    TRANS *current;
    current = codet;
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("%s %s\n", current->word1, current->word2);
        current = current->next;
    } 
}

void reverse(LINK **head)
{
    struct node *prev   = NULL;
    struct node *current = *head;
    struct node *next = NULL;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next  = current->next;  
        current->next = prev;   
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    *head = prev;
}

LINK *insertList(char *wordt, LINK *head)
{
    LINK *current, *temp;
    temp = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
    temp->words = (char*)calloc(strlen(wordt)+1, sizeof(char));

    strcpy(temp->words, wordt);

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
        head = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;

        return head;
    }

    current = head;

    if (strcmp(current->words, wordt))
    {
        temp->next = current;
        head = temp;

        return head;
    }

    current = head;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->next == NULL || strcmp(current->next->words, wordt))
        {
            temp->next = current->next;
            current->next = temp;

            return head;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}

TRANS *insertCodex(char *codeword, char *replace, TRANS *codet)
{
    TRANS *current, *temp;

    temp = (TRANS *)malloc(sizeof(TRANS));
    temp->word1 = (char*)calloc(strlen(codeword)+1, sizeof(char));
    temp->word2 = (char*)calloc(strlen(replace)+1, sizeof(char));

    strcpy(temp->word1, codeword);
    strcpy(temp->word2, replace);

    if (codet == NULL)
    {
        codet = (TRANS *)malloc(sizeof(TRANS));
        codet = temp;
        temp->next = NULL;

        return codet;
    }

    current = codet;

    if (strcmp(current->word1, codeword) && strcmp(current->word2, replace))
    {
        temp->next = current;
        codet = temp;

        return codet;
    }

    current = codet;

    while (current != NULL)
    {
        if (current->next == NULL || strcmp(current->next->word1, codeword) && strcmp(current->next->word2, replace))
        {
            temp->next = current->next;
            current->next = temp;

            return codet;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
}

TRANS *scanCodex(FILE *code, TRANS *codet)
{
    char *codeword = (char*)malloc(13*sizeof(char));
    char *replace = (char*)malloc(13*sizeof(char));

    while(1)
    {
        fscanf(code, "%s %s", codeword, replace);
        if (feof(code)) break;
        codet = insertCodex(codeword, replace, codet);
    }
    fclose(code);

    return codet;
}

LINK *scanInsert(FILE *stream, LINK *head)
{
    char *input = (char*)malloc(13*sizeof(char));

    while (1)
    {
        fscanf(stream, "%s", input);
        if(feof(stream)) break;
        head = insertList(input, head);
    }

    fclose(stream);

    return head;
}

LINK *decoder(TRANS *codet, LINK *head)
{
    LINK *currentt;
    currentt = head;
    TRANS *current;
    current = codet;
    printf("Decoding...\n");

    while (currentt != NULL)
    {
        current = codet;
        while (1)
        {
            if ()
            printf("Comparing %s with %s: \n", currentt->words, current->word1);
            if (!strcmp(currentt->words, current->word1))
            {
                printf("Replacing...\n");
                currentt->words = (char*)calloc(strlen(current->word2), sizeof(char));
                strcpy(currentt->words, current->word2);
                break;
            }
            current = current->next;
        }
        currentt = currentt->next;  
    }

    return head;
}

int main (void)
{
    FILE *stream = fopen("hw10data.txt", "r");
    FILE *code = fopen("hw10codex.txt", "r");
    LINK *head;
    TRANS *codet;
    head = NULL;
    codet = NULL;

    head = scanInsert(stream, head);
    reverse(&head);
    printInsert(head);

    codet = scanCodex(code, codet);
    printCodex(codet);
    head = decoder(codet, head);
    printInsert(head);
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Basically, you want to know how to make `fscanf(stream, "%s", input);` parse words separately from punctuation, i.e. tokenize them? Are you sure that the input poem needs to be tokenized into a linked list, opposed to simply convert it on the fly?

Comment: `strcmp` will not distinguish between letters and punctuation but you can easily write your own comparison function that does and call that instead

Comment: Post the contents of the data files. Otherwise, you have not provided [**A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final code if you need it:

```js
//Tristan Shepherd

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

struct node
{
 char *words;
 struct node *next;
};

struct codex
{
 char *word1;
 char *word2;
 struct codex *next;
};

typedef struct node LINK;
typedef struct codex TRANS;

void delete(LINK **head, char *key)
{
    LINK *temp = *head, *prev;

    if (temp != NULL && !strcmp(temp->words, key))
    {
        *head = temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return;
    }

    while (temp != NULL && strcmp(temp->words, key))
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    if (temp == NULL) return;

    prev->next = temp->next;
 
    free(temp);
}

void printInsert(LINK *head, int aftersort) 
{
 printf("\n\nPrinting list: \n\n");
 LINK *current;
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) 
    {
     if (aftersort)
     {
      printf("%s", current->words);
     }
     else
     {
      printf("%s ", current->words);
     }
        current = current->next;
    } 
}

void printCodex(TRANS *codet) 
{
 printf("\n\nPrinting codex: \n\n");
 TRANS *current;
    current = codet;
    while (current != NULL) 
    {
        printf("%s %s\n", current->word1, current->word2);
        current = current->next;
    } 
}

void reverse(LINK **head)
{
    struct node *prev   = NULL;
    struct node *current = *head;
    struct node *next = NULL;
    while (current != NULL)
    {
        next  = current->next;  
        current->next = prev;   
        prev = current;
        current = next;
    }
    *head = prev;
}

LINK *insertList(char *wordt, LINK *head)
{
 LINK *current, *temp;
 temp = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
 temp->words = (char*)calloc(strlen(wordt)+1, sizeof(char));

 strcpy(temp->words, wordt);

 if (head == NULL)
 {
  head = (LINK *)malloc(sizeof(LINK));
  head = temp;
  temp->next = NULL;

  return head;
 }

 current = head;

 if (strcmp(current->words, wordt))
 {
  temp->next = current;
  head = temp;

  return head;
 }

 current = head;

 while (current != NULL)
 {
  if (current->next == NULL || strcmp(current->next->words, wordt))
  {
   temp->next = current->next;
   current->next = temp;

   return head;
  }
  current = current->next;
 }
}

TRANS *insertCodex(char *codeword, char *replace, TRANS *codet)
{
 TRANS *current, *temp;

 temp = (TRANS *)malloc(sizeof(TRANS));
 temp->word1 = (char*)calloc(strlen(codeword)+1, sizeof(char));
 temp->word2 = (char*)calloc(strlen(replace)+1, sizeof(char));

 strcpy(temp->word1, codeword);
 strcpy(temp->word2, replace);

 if (codet == NULL)
 {
  codet = (TRANS *)malloc(sizeof(TRANS));
  codet = temp;
  temp->next = NULL;

  return codet;
 }

 current = codet;

 if (strcmp(current->word1, codeword) && strcmp(current->word2, replace))
 {
  temp->next = current;
  codet = temp;

  return codet;
 }

 current = codet;

 while (current != NULL)
 {
  if (current->next == NULL || strcmp(current->next->word1, codeword) && strcmp(current->next->word2, replace))
  {
   temp->next = current->next;
   current->next = temp;

   return codet;
  }
  current = current->next;
 }
}

TRANS *scanCodex(FILE *code, TRANS *codet)
{
 char *codeword = (char*)malloc(13*sizeof(char));
 char *replace = (char*)malloc(13*sizeof(char));

 while(1)
 {
  fscanf(code, "%s %s", codeword, replace);
  if (feof(code)) break;
  codet = insertCodex(codeword, replace, codet);
 }
 fclose(code);

 return codet;
}

LINK *scanInsert(FILE *stream, LINK *head)
{
 char *input = (char*)malloc(13*sizeof(char));

 while (1)
 {
  fscanf(stream, "%s", input);
  if(feof(stream)) break;
  head = insertList(input, head);
 }

 fclose(stream);

 return head;
}

LINK *decoder(TRANS *codet, LINK *head)
{
 LINK *currentt;
 currentt = head;
 TRANS *current;
 current = codet;
 char *temp = (char*)malloc(33*sizeof(char));

 while (currentt != NULL)
 {
  int CorP = 0;
  int punct = 0;
  int t = 0;
  current = codet;
  while (1)
  {
   if (!strcmp(currentt->words, current->word1))
   {
    currentt->words = (char*)calloc(strlen(current->word2)+1, sizeof(char));
    strcpy(currentt->words, current->word2);
    strcat(currentt->words, " ");
    if (punct == 1)
    {
     strtok(currentt->words, " ");
     strcat(currentt->words, ".\n");
    }
    if (punct == 2)
    {
     strtok(currentt->words, " ");
     strcat(currentt->words, ",\n");
    }

    if (!strcmp(currentt->words, "skip "))
    {
     delete(&head, currentt->words);
    }
    break;
   }
   
   current = current->next;

   if (current == NULL)
   {
    strcpy(temp, currentt->words);
    if (!strcmp(currentt->words, strtok(temp, ".")))
    {
     if(!strcmp(currentt->words, strtok(temp, ",")))
     {
      if(t == 1)
      {
       strcat(currentt->words, " ");
       if (punct == 1)
       {
        strtok(currentt->words, " ");
        strcat(currentt->words, ".\n");
       }
       if (punct == 2)
       {
        strtok(currentt->words, " ");
        strcat(currentt->words, ",\n");
       }
       break;
      }
      t++;
     }
     else
     {
      strcpy(currentt->words, strtok(currentt->words, ","));
      current = codet;
      punct = 2;
     }
    }
    else
    {
     strcpy(currentt->words, strtok(currentt->words, "."));
     current = codet;
     punct = 1;
    }
    current = codet;
   }
  }
  currentt = currentt->next; 
 }

 return head;
}

int main (void)
{
 FILE *stream = fopen("hw10data.txt", "r");
 FILE *code = fopen("hw10codex.txt", "r");
 LINK *head;
 TRANS *codet;
 head = NULL;
 codet = NULL;

 head = scanInsert(stream, head);
 reverse(&head);
 printInsert(head, 0);

 codet = scanCodex(code, codet);
 printCodex(codet);
 head = decoder(codet, head);
 printInsert(head, 1);
 exit(0);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

@David C. Rankin

Contents of the Files:

File 1:

Eye I
eye I
chequer checker 
Pea P
Sea C
plane plainly
lee skip 
four for
revue review
Miss Mistakes
Steaks skip
knot not
sea see
quays keys
whirred word
weight wait
Two To
two to
Weather Whether
write right 
oar or
aweigh away
threw through
Your You're 
shore sure 
two to 
no know
Its It's
vary very
weigh way
tolled told
sew so
bless blessed
freeze frees
yew you 
lodes loads 
thyme time
right write
stiles styles
righting writing
aides aids
rime rhyme
frays phrase
come composed
posed skip
trussed trusted
too to 
bee be
joule jewel
cheque check
sum some

File 2:

Eye have a spelling chequer, 
It came with my Pea Sea.
It plane lee marks four my revue, 
Miss Steaks I can knot sea.
Eye strike the quays and type a whirred,
And weight four it two say,
Weather eye am write oar wrong,
It tells me straight aweigh.
Eye ran this poem threw it,
Your shore real glad two no.
Its vary polished in its weigh.
My chequer tolled me sew.
A chequer is a bless thing,
It freeze yew lodes of thyme.
It helps me right all stiles of righting,
And aides me when eye rime.
Each frays come posed up on my screen,
Eye trussed too bee a joule.
The chequer pours over every word,
Two cheque sum spelling rule.